# Change value of a variable on click event in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have added a new variable and i am appending an onclick function to initialize the "keyword" to new variable.But it doesnot seem to work.
I am trying to initialize the variable with the selected rectangle's keyword label
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/13/)

I am using this to do the same.

```
                  .on('click',function(d){
                        selectedkeyword = d.keyword;
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code you pasted *will* work, that's not the problem. The actual problem is visible when you analise the whole block, with a proper indentation:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var xPos = 70 + parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('w'));
    var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + yScale.rangeBand() + 30;
    .on('click', function(d) {//incorrect position!
        selectedkeyword = d.keyword;
    });

    d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style('left', xPos + 'px')
        .style('top', yPos + 'px')
        .style('display', 'block')
        .select('#value')
        .text(d.global);

    d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
})
```

You have the `click` handler inside the `mouseover` handler, and it makes no sense. So, it should work if you change for this:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var xPos = 70 + parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('w'));
    var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + yScale.rangeBand() + 30;

    d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style('left', xPos + 'px')
        .style('top', yPos + 'px')
        .style('display', 'block')
        .select('#value')
        .text(d.global);

        d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
    })
.on('click', function(d) {
    selectedkeyword = d.keyword;
});
```

But this is also **not** working. The explanation is simple: if you go up the code, you'll see that you're appending texts to rectangles, and that's not valid in an SVG. So, you have 2 problems.

Appending the texts to `sets` selection will work:

```
sets.append("text")
    //etc...
    .on('click', function(d) {
        selectedkeyword = d.keyword;
        console.log(selectedkeyword);
    });
```

Here is your fiddle, click in the texts on the top and check the console: https://jsfiddle.net/0x7emgnt/